# How to remove/hidden controller name from url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This belove is my url. so how can i remove/hidden

```
home/post
```

from the url

```
http://localhost/likes/home/post/sports/Secret-Weapons-for-Top-NFL-Teams-/13
```

and

```
     admin/ad_managment
```

from

```
   http://localhost/likes/admin/ad_managment/edit/2
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check user guide of codeigniter and in this [example](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/news_section.html) see how the routing done.
Read more about code-igniter routing

Answer (score 3):

Try this I haven't tried this should work,

```
$route['(:any)/(:num)'] = "admin/ad_managment/$1/$2";
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = "home/post/$1/$2/$3";
```

See more http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: now 
http://localhost/likes/home/post/sports/Secret-Weapons-for-Top-NFL-Teams-/13
not working

Answer (score 0):

Write into `application/config/routes.php`

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = "home/post/$1/$2/$3";
```

And now, you can use like following format:

```
http://localhost/likes/sports/Secret-Weapons-for-Top-NFL-Teams-/13
```

**Uri Routing Document:** http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Your base url `http://localhost/likes/` or `http://localhost/`? And what you get?

Comment: Hmm you get any error? and `home` controller, `post` method, and have 3 params, is it right?

Comment: ya home controller, post method, and have 3 params

Answer (score 0):

use .htaccess to rewrite the url.

http://www.pets.com/pet_care_info_07_07_2008.php
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^pet-care/?$    pet_care_info_01_02_2008.php    [NC,L]
    # Handle requests for "pet-care"

https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/